# How do I build a Docker image for a Ruby project without build tools?

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems

I'm trying to build a Docker image for a Ruby project. The problem is the project has some gem dependencies that need to build native extensions. My understanding is that I have a couple of choices:

1. Start with a base image that already has build tools installed.
2. Use a base image with no build tools, install build tools as a step in the Dockerfile before running `bundle install`.
3. Precompile the native extensions on the host, vendorize the gem, and simply copy the resulting bundle into the image.

1 & 2 seem to require that the resulting image contains the build tools needed to build the native extensions. I'm trying to avoid that scenario for security reasons. 3 is cumbersome, but doable, and would accomplish what I want.

Are there any options I'm missing or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Not sure for what reasons exactly you're trying to avoid having build tools in the image, but doesn't simply uninstalling them in a `RUN` step after `bundle install` accomplish what you want?

Comment: @EvgenyChernyavskiy My understanding is that because Docker uses a union file system even if you uninstall or delete things in a `RUN` step the files are still accessible in the image. As for why I don't want build tools in the image, one is because of bloat, two is because of attack surface. If build tools aren't installed an attacker doesn't have the option of compiling arbitrary code on my machines.

Comment: @jvergeldedios more importantly, this is about building the *right* execution environment, the one which contains *only* what you need to run your service instead of including as well a bunch of unrelated tools (needed at some point to build parts of the service): you want to end up with an environment not polluted by side-effects introduced by the presence of said unrelated tools. Hence my option 3 detailed below.

Comment: There's some good discussion around this here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12113/installing-development-tools-on-production-server-security-risk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use option 3 all the time, the goal being to end up with an image which has only what I need to *run* (not to compile)

For example, [here I build and install Apache first](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/9a532a80de6a0a30656ac9488f200ee072283d16/apache/build#L6-L14), before using the resulting image as a base image for my (patched and recompiled) Apache setup.

Build:

```
if [ "$(docker images -q apache.deb 2> /dev/null)" = "" ]; then
  docker build -t apache.deb -f Dockerfile.build . || exit 1
fi
```

The [Dockerfile.build](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/9a532a80de6a0a30656ac9488f200ee072283d16/apache/Dockerfile.build#L29-L31) declares a volume which contains the resulting Apache recompiled (in a deb file)

```
RUN checkinstall --pkgname=apache2-4 --pkgversion="2.4.10" --backup=no --deldoc=yes --fstrans=no --default
RUN mkdir $HOME/deb && mv *.deb $HOME/deb
VOLUME /root/deb
```

Installation:

```
if [ "$(docker images -q apache.inst 2> /dev/null)" = "" ]; then
    docker inspect apache.deb.cont > /dev/null 2>&1 || docker run -d -t --name=apache.deb.cont apache.deb
    docker inspect apache.inst.cont > /dev/null 2>&1 || docker run -u root -it --name=apache.inst.cont --volumes-from apache.deb.cont --entrypoint "/bin/sh" openldap -c "dpkg -i /root/deb/apache2-4_2.4.10-1_amd64.deb"
    docker commit apache.inst.cont apache.inst
    docker rm apache.deb.cont apache.inst.cont
fi
```

Here I install the deb using another image (in my case 'openldap') as a base image:

```
docker run -u root -it --name=apache.inst.cont --volumes-from apache.deb.cont --entrypoint "/bin/sh" openldap -c "dpkg -i /root/deb/apache2-4_2.4.10-1_amd64.deb"
docker commit apache.inst.cont apache.inst
```

Finally I have a [regular Dockerfile](http://docker%20commit%20apache.inst.cont%20apache.inst) starting from the image I just committed.

```
FROM apache.inst:latest
```

---

[psmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446220/psmith) points out in the comments to [Building Minimal Docker Image for Rails App](http://blog.kontena.io/building-minimal-docker-image-for-rails/) from [Jari Kolehmainen](https://twitter.com/kolehja).
For a ruby application, you can remove the part needed for the build easily with:

```
bundle install --without development test && \
apk del build-dependencies
```

Since ruby is needed to *run* the application anyway, that works great in this case.

I my case, I still need a separate image for building, as `gcc` is not needed to run Apache (and it is quite large, comes with multiple dependencies, some of them needed by Apache at runtime, some not...)

Comment: So for example, if I wanted a base Ruby image the steps would be to build Ruby in one image, create a package from the resulting binaries, add that package to a volume on that image, mount that volume in a new image, install the package? Then for my application dependencies I would use my new base image, build the native dependencies on the host (assuming the architecture is the same) and just copy them into the image in my Dockerfile.

Comment: @jvergeldedios yes, that is the idea, that I used multiple time whenever a tool/package was not directly available.

Comment: This seems like a simpler approach to achieve the reduced image size: http://blog.kontena.io/building-minimal-docker-image-for-rails/

Comment: @psmith Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility (as well as a reason why my approach is needed in my case)