# Docker build image 1GB or too big

Tags: docker, dockerfile, coreos

I have a Docker build file in my Maven Java project to build it.  The docker image ends being about 1GB.  All I want to do is build the war artifact and keep the size down.  Here is what I have so far:

```
FROM java:8

#FROM maven:latest
MAINTAINER Sonam <myemail@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y maven

WORKDIR /code

#Prepare by downloading dependencies
ADD pom.xml /code/pom.xml
RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]
RUN ["mvn", "verify"]

#Adding source, compile and package into a fat jar
ADD src /code/src

RUN ["mvn", "clean"]
RUN ["mvn", "install", "-Dmaven.test.skip=true"]

RUN mkdir webapps

CMD ["echo"] ["hello"]
```

I have a CoreOS unit file where when this container is run I want to copy the war to another file.

Answer (score 1):

You can see an alternative in "[How do I build a Docker image for a Ruby project without build tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34759675/6309)"

- I use an image to build,
- I commit the resulting stopped container as a new image (with a volume including the resulting binary)
- I use an execution image (one which only contain what you need to run), and copy the binary from the other image. I commit again the resulting container.

The final image includes the compiled binary and the execution environment.

In your case, make sure your current Dockerfile declares a volume and produces the war (from the maven compilation) in it.

Then commit the exited container as a new temporary "compilation" image.
Use another Dockerfile which will run and copy the war "from-volume" of your compilation image.

```
docker run -u root -it --name=installation.cont --volumes-from compilation.cont --entrypoint "/bin/sh" installation.image -c "cp /avolume/myway /to/my/path"
```

The resulting stopped container `installation.cont` can be committed as an image `installation.image`.

Then you can write a *third* Dockerfile, starting from that image: `FROM installation.image` (which includes only your war), and adding what you need to in order to use that war.
docker commit apache.inst.cont apache.inst

Comment: It looks complex but will see if I can corporate your ideas.  Thanks Vonc

Comment: @Sonam It does but the basic idea is to build your binary in one container, and copy it over another container which, once committed, will be your base image.